# React Js using useState to create animations

Tags: javascript, reactjs

basically i have the following problem i have a state that starts as false and after that clicked to true
and each true and false state has a different animation, but always when assembling the component I already start with the animation and I wanted to start the animation with just a click

problem:

[image]

**JSX**

```
const NavMain = () => {
  const [isOpenBox, setOpenBox] = React.useState(false);
  console.log(isOpenBox);
  return (
    <Nav>
      <Container>
        <NavBetween>
          <WrapLogo>a</WrapLogo>
          <NavGrid>
            <NavUl isOpen={isOpenBox}>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <FontAwesomeIcon
                  onClick={() => setOpenBox(!isOpenBox)}
                  className="searchIcon"
                  rotation={90}
                  icon={faSearch}
                  size="1x"
                  fixedWidth
                  color="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);"
                />
              </li>
            </NavUl>
            <SearchWrapper isOpen={isOpenBox}>
              <div className="FlexInput">
                <input placeholder="Pesquisar" />
                <div className="IconContainer">
                  <FontAwesomeIcon
                    onClick={() => setOpenBox(!isOpenBox)}
                    className="searchIcon"
                    icon={faTimes}
                    size="xs"
                    fixedWidth
                    color="black"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </SearchWrapper>
          </NavGrid>
        </NavBetween>
      </Container>
    </Nav>
  );
};
```

**CSS IN JS**

```
const KeySearch = keyframes`
from { 
  z-index:2;
  visibility: visible; 
  transform: translateY(0); 
  opacity: 1;
 }
to   { 
  z-index:1;
  visibility: hidden; 
  transform: translateY(20px); 
  opacity: 0; display:none;
}
`;
const KeySearch2 = keyframes`
from {
  z-index:1;
  visibility: hidden; 
  transform: translateY(20px); 
  opacity: 0; display:none;

 }
to   { 
    z-index:2;
  visibility: visible; 
  transform: translateY(0); 
  opacity: 1;
}
`;
export const Nav = styled.nav`
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background: #fff;
`;
export const NavBetween = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
`;
export const Container = styled.div`
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 80rem !important;
`;

export const NavGrid = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
`;
export const NavUl = styled.ul`
  z-index: 2;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  ${props =>
    props.isOpen
      ? css`
          animation: ${KeySearch} 0.5s;
          -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
          -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
          -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
          -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
          animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        `
      : css`
          animation: ${KeySearch2} 0.5s;
          -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
          -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
          -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
          -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
          animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        `}
  svg {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  a {
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    display: block;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    padding: 16px 20px;
    line-height: 24px;
    :hover {
      color: #cdcdcd;
      transition-duration: 0.5s;
      transition-property: background-color, color;
    }
  }
`;

export const WrapLogo = styled.div`
  width: 30%;
  img {
    height: 40px;
  }
`;

export const SearchWrapper = styled.div`
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  & .FlexInput {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    transition: all 0.4s;
    input {
      background: transparent;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border: 0;
      padding: 0.5rem 0.8rem 0.5rem 1.2rem;
      outline: none;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: 400;
      color: #a9a9a9;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
      box-sizing: initial;
      font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    }
  }
  & .IconContainer {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    :hover {
      color: white;
    }
  }
`;
```

EXAMPLE

> https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-sammet-9qim9

Comment: Are you trying to show this animation with just a single click?

Comment: yes but i have two animation to close and to open

Comment: basically when I close it I will show another component and then when I open it I will show it with the reverse animation, but I have doubts as to how I could achieve this

Comment: yeahh i have live:gabrielcerqueira96

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code -

```
import React from "react";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import "./styles.css";
import {
  faSearch,
  faAdjust,
  faAngleDown
} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { faTimes } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import {
  Container,
  Nav,
  NavBetween,
  WrapLogo,
  NavGrid,
  NavUl,
  SearchWrapper
} from "./styled";

const NavMain = () => {
  const [isOpenBox, setOpenBox] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <Nav>
      <Container>
        <NavBetween>
          <WrapLogo>a</WrapLogo>
          <NavGrid>
            <NavUl isOpen={isOpenBox}>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <FontAwesomeIcon
                  onClick={() => setOpenBox(!isOpenBox)}
                  className="searchIcon"
                  rotation={90}
                  icon={faSearch}
                  size="1x"
                  fixedWidth
                  color="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);"
                />
              </li>
            </NavUl>
            {isOpenBox && (
              <SearchWrapper>
                <div className="FlexInput">
                  <input placeholder="Pesquisar" />
                  <div className="IconContainer">
                    <FontAwesomeIcon
                      onClick={() => setOpenBox(!isOpenBox)}
                      className="searchIcon"
                      icon={faTimes}
                      size="xs"
                      fixedWidth
                      color="black"
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </SearchWrapper>
            )}
          </NavGrid>
        </NavBetween>
      </Container>
    </Nav>
  );
};

export default NavMain;
```